# Issue with Copying files from and too within certain dates in Powershell

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am new to power shell, I am trying to copy files from one location to another between specific dates.

I have an issue with the dates part it seems to be copying all the files regardless of the dates, any idea why?

```
$StartDate = (Get-date).Addyears(-2)
$EndDate = (Get-date).Adddays(-2)
$src = "C:\Sites\T\Test01" 
$dst = "C:\Customer\" 

Get-ChildItem $src -exclude "Aeromark" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination $dst -Force |
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime.Date -ge $StartDate.Date) -and ($_.LastWriteTime.Date -le $EndDate.Date)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Where-Object` needs to go before `Copy-Item` in your particular case. The `Copy-Item` command is being called before `Where-Object` excludes the files based on date.

Here is your code re-arranged:

```
Get-ChildItem $src -exclude "Aeromark" -Recurse | 
Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime.Date -ge $StartDate.Date) -and ($_.LastWriteTime.Date -le $EndDate.Date)} | 
Copy-Item -Destination $dst -Force
```

Comment: Thank you for that

Comment: @Laali Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: It did thanks, sorry i am new at this. I have marked it as the answer now :)